# NodeJS site hits server error when MongoDB is NOT empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using  Node.js with MongoDB and Mongoose for my database connection. What happens is, if there are no values in the database, then the callback function renders the followup page fine (although of course nothing is shown where the template expects to see values), but if their are values, I'm faced with `Press any key to continue...` in the command line.

Here is the route that handles the request to a page that should show all values in a collection

```
// GET request for the Blog page.
exports.g_blog = function (req, res) {
    var image = req.Image;

    image.find(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log(docs); // Prints the value we save initially
        res.render('blog', {
            title : 'Blog',
            images: docs
        });
    });
};
```

In the above code, `Image` is an instance of a Model defined in a schema file.
That definition is as follows

```
var ImageSchema = new Schema({
    path : String
});

var Image = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema);
```

So calling `image.find` in the `GET` request should return all the values in the collection, which is stored in the variable `docs`

I've confirmed that it reaches this point in the code through the `console.log(docs)` function call, where either an empty array or a populated array is shown. In the case of a populated array, I am met with the above message. In an empty array, the following GET request information is output.

Here is an example of what I see when the result set of the DB query is empty.

[image: Empty Array]

And here is an example of what will happen once I've added some values.

[image]

In the meantime, Chrome hangs up for about 3 seconds while this is happening, and then displays an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` message. Additionally, pressing any key when prompted to do so just closes the terminal tab.

Any help?

Comment: What is `img_collection`? Not mentioned anywhere in the code you have listed, so you are clearly doing something else. It's not likely a problem with the result from the `.find()` since indeed you do log that, but the `res.render()` call by all accounts is not acutally happening. So more likely problems there, and/or with the variable mentioned earlier.

Comment: @BlakesSeven `img_collection` was a variable I was trying to save the `docs` values into from a global context. It wasn't working (and felt like poor practice) so I ditched that idea.It's been removed in my original source code as well, and the problem persists with the exact same behaviour. I updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: Short shrift is, okay you've given us the backstory and screenshots but really we don't need them. Give a clear and reproducible case to what is happening. That gives people something to work with and often dispells misconceptions of what the actual problem is. You aren't showing all the code that matters. Also statements like *"trying to save"*? What do you mean? All we see here is a `.find()` request and no reason to believe anything else is in scope. Give us a reproducible case. The code as presented should error on the `undefined variable`. Make it clear. Make it true.

Comment: I'm not sure what other code you'd need to see that could help really. The only other code that relates these functions is a call to app.get('/blog', routes.g_blog) where routes is the require cal to the JS file that contains the above code for exports.g_blog. I've explained clearly that, all else the same, the only thing required to break the system is a populated DB or not. If there is other code you think would be necessary to see to help with this, I'd be more than willing to oblige, but I've provided what I believe is the entire relevant context. @BlakesSeven

Comment: How about editing some more detail in your question rather than talking about it. The friendly and patient advice here is telling you *"Not enough information in here for me to see/reproduce the problem"*. So more is more. Already gave you the good pointer in that the line of code where output is not happening is where the likely problem is, and you can already see the result of the `.find()`, so the next line is .... See the point?

Comment: So it's all about everything involved with that very next line, and all of the detail around that ( 1. Where the variable content comes from, 2. What's in the template being rendered? ) all missing from the question. The problem is not where you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

<==================Code for Mongodb Model===========================>

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    var ImageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        path : String
    });

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Image', ImageSchema );
```

<=============Code for Routing + Functionality (image.js File)===============>

```
    var imageModel = require(../pathTo/yourModel.js);

    module exports = (function () {

        var ImageApi= express.Router();

        image.find(function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
               console.error(err);
            }
            else{
               console.log(docs); // Prints the value we save initially
               if(docs.length <=0){
                  console.log("No records found");
                  res.render('blog', {
                  title : 'Blog',
                  images: "No Records Found"
                  });
                }else{ 
               res.render('blog', {
                  title : 'Blog',
                  images: docs
               });
              }
            }
        });
      return ImageApi;
    })();
```

<==================Code for App.js File===========================>

```
 var imageApi = = require('./routes/image.js');

 app.use('/image', imageApi);
```

I think now it should be cleared to you... Here Routing you have to change according to your file name and functionality

Thanks & Cheers

Comment: The question was not asking *"How do I handle a response when no documents are found?"*, it's just not a really good title for the question. If you read the OP's question carefully, there is indeed a match to the query and content returned ( so not `null` ), but then an error occurs after that. My commentary on the question is trying to get the OP to expose both the source of the variable used in the `res.render()` call, as well as the referenced template. That is the cause of their "crash". So you have misinterpreted the question. Also, please don't overuse **BOLD** when you write.